# Workflow suspended

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a SharePoint 2013 workflow developed using vs2012.

What the workflow mainly should do is, when a user change the value stored in a certain column (lookup type), it should add the username to another column (people type).

To capture the username I have used "`LookUpWorkflowContextProperty - Initiator`".

But when the workflow is executed, it goes to "Suspended" state.

Could some please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Following is the error I get

```
RequestorId: 5fb08905-5d95-7e26-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.FormatException: Expected hex 0x in '{0}'. at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument) at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithHexPrefix(String guidString, GuidResult& result) at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result) at System.Guid.Parse(String input) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```